# Choose between Mann-Whitney test and Wilcoxon?

Tags: self-study, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I'm practicing this test and I have a trouble with this question:

> Students' scores on the mathematics test are given in the following table. The students are divided into two groups: those who are given study guide (group 1) and those who are not (group 2).
>
> Group 1   Group 2
>   70  6  88  57  79  68  85  14  88   77  72  54  87  85  62  77  86
>   55  82  92  87  45  85  84  57  56
>   To test if the median of students' scores of group 1 is higher than that of group 2, which test is most appropriate between the Mann-Whitney Test or the Wilcoxon Signed-Rank test?

I believe that the best test to use is the Wilcoxon because of the paired samples but I'm not sure.

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Comment: Well i believe that the best test to use is the Wilcoxon because of the pair samples but im not sure @gung

Comment: Add that to your question, & please add the tag & read the wiki.

Comment: Well my question is basically how do you know for sure if the Wilcoxon is the best test to use for this problem? I mean arent the two groups consider a pair sample? and sorry im new to this website but i would appreciate your help @gung

Comment: What makes you think the data are paired?

Comment: well they come from the same population ? @gung

Comment: You certainly start w/ a single group of students--that's always true. What about the 2nd sentence? Does that suggest paired or unpaired?

Comment: Can you say what it means for values to be paired?

Answer (score 2):

The question does not suggest that the two samples are paired strategically. The Wilcoxon signed-rank test should be used when the two samples are paired strategically, otherwise use the Mann-Whitney U test.

An example of this:
Suppose we have a classroom of 20 sets of twins. Group 1 contained the first-born twin, and group 2 contained the other twin. Group 1 was taught using method 1, and group 2 was taught using method 2. If we wanted to test for a difference in median test scores, we would use the Wilcoxon signed-rank test here.

In my example, the pairings are obviously strategic - group 1 has a corresponding member in group 2 (his/her twin).

In your example, there are no corresponding members between groups. To check this, ask yourself, is person 1 of group 1 tied to person 1 of group 2 in any relevant way?